# How does MySql sort data when the data of the sort filed is duplicate?

Tags: mysql

## How dose MySql sort data when the data of sort filed is duplicate?

### The table:

```
CREATE TABLE `orderby_test` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sort1` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `sort2` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `a` bigint(20) NOT NULL ,
  `b` bigint(20) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_sort` (`sort1`, `sort2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

### sql :

```
select id, sort1,sort2,a,b from  orderby_test where sort1 = 1 and a = 1 and b = 1 order by sort2 desc limit 0, 1000
```

### then insert data 3 times:

```
    insert into orderby_test (sort1,sort2,a,b) values (1,3,1,1);
```

### then select, result is:

```
id  sort1   sort2   a   b
1   1   3   1   1
2   1   3   1   1
3   1   3   1   1
```

### the id is ASC

### then insert data 20 times:

```
    insert into orderby_test (sort1,sort2,a,b) values (1,3,1,1);
```

### then select, result is:

```
id  sort1   sort2   a   b
12  1   3   1   1
23  1   3   1   1
22  1   3   1   1
21  1   3   1   1
20  1   3   1   1
19  1   3   1   1
18  1   3   1   1
17  1   3   1   1
16  1   3   1   1
15  1   3   1   1
14  1   3   1   1
13  1   3   1   1
1   1   3   1   1
11  1   3   1   1
10  1   3   1   1
9   1   3   1   1
8   1   3   1   1
7   1   3   1   1
6   1   3   1   1
5   1   3   1   1
4   1   3   1   1
3   1   3   1   1
2   1   3   1   1
```

### id is not sorted！

why?

---

### if you do more insert

### the result :

```
select id, sort1,sort2,a,b from  orderby_test where sort1 = 1 and a = 1 and b = 1 order by sort2 desc limit 0, 20
```

```
id  sort1   sort2   a   b
282 1   3   1   1
281 1   3   1   1
280 1   3   1   1
279 1   3   1   1
278 1   3   1   1
277 1   3   1   1
276 1   3   1   1
275 1   3   1   1
274 1   3   1   1
273 1   3   1   1
272 1   3   1   1
271 1   3   1   1
270 1   3   1   1
269 1   3   1   1
268 1   3   1   1
267 1   3   1   1
266 1   3   1   1
265 1   3   1   1
259 1   3   1   1
258 1   3   1   1
```

### id is sorted again！

**because the implement of B+ tree in innodb?  how does mysql do it?**

mysql version   :   5.7.21-21-log

Comment: In summary, MySQL or any RDBMS cannot and will not promise any particular sort order except for the column you specified.

Answer (score 3):

> How does MySql sort data when the data of the sort filed is duplicate?

It doesn't.

Once MySQL has enough information to arrange the result-set in such a way that it complies with the `ORDER BY` clause, it just packs the rows with ties as fast as it can, not caring at all about its relative order.

This is not specific to MySQL, it's how SQL is designed to behave. Sorting has a cost (time, CPU, memory...); there's no point in paying such cost when sorting is not needed.

Comment: could you tell me how innodb implemented ORDER BY?   i think it use the  KEY `idx_sort` (`sort1`, `sort2`) ,  and then find data through `id` .  But why the `id` is not sorted?

Comment: If you're asking about the exact events that lead to that specific order in that specific query in that specific database instance in that specific moment... I have no idea, sorry. Just neither assume it's intentional, nor rely on it.

Comment: @Syn No, it (ORDER BY) does not sort, then use id to find the data.  If there is no index, you can figure it creates a temporary index.  It uses the index to get all the records of the table in the order of the sort fields.  So it only uses the sort fields, and does not use `id`.

Comment: @Syn A more complete answer, the database does use an internal `rid` (record id), which is different than your `id` field, and is not the primary key.  It uses the `rid` in indexes.  But since it is an internal `rid` and not the `id` field, the records are not sorted by `id`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the second ordering preference:

```
...ORDER BY sort2 DESC, id ASC ...
```

Comment: otherwise Mysql will do exactly what you asked order by a single specific column..